# Error al calcular una operación y al dar 0 en variable double

Tags: c#

Mi error es el siguiente, tengo un ciclo que me calcula a través de una formula un valor 0, ese valor se almacena en una variable `double`, el algoritmo calcula un rango de -100 hasta 100 que al multiplicar cada número y sumarlo con `n` números me da como resultado 0, el detalle es el siguiente, que al darme 0 me almacena un valor desconocido en la variable `double`. El valor es algo así como -1.5533e15 y los demás si lo almacena de maravilla pero cuando justamente toca el numero que da 0 me da ese resultado.

```
void Motorprimario(double Nprimario, double Nfinal, int columna)
{
    double numerodevuelto = 0, iposs = 0; int n1, n2, n3; bool jo = false, otramul = false;
    do
    {
        numerodevuelto = ((iposs * Nprimario) + Nfinal);

        if (jo == true)
        {
            iposs -= 0.01;
        }
        else
            iposs += 0.01;
    } while (numerodevuelto != 0);
}
```

Comente los resultados calculados por calculo y cuando toca llegar a 0 me da como resultado 1.33227e-015 en vez de 0.

Comment: ojo solo ocurre cuando el resultado llega a 0 de resto todo va perfecto.

Comment: Moises, danos un ejemplo con que valores te pasa el error para poder simularlo.

Comment: es un algoritmo de gauss jordan simplificacion de matrices, este motor busca un numero de una posicion de una matriz, lo multiplica por el rango de numeros en este caso la variable iposs, aunque lo he probado con distintos numeros y da lo mismo pero mientras tanto el valor de la variable Nprimario=-2 y la varable Nfinal=1.

Comment: perdon corrijo Nprimario=2 Nfinal=-1

Comment: realice este pequeño algoritmo el cual me ad el mismo resultado:

void lol(double num1=2,double num2=-1)
{
 double num,i=0;
 do
 { 
 num=(num2*i)+num1;
 cout<<"i:= "<<i<<endl;
 cout<<"num:= "<<num<<endl;
 i+=0.01;
 
}
 }while (num!=0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
 lol();
}

Comment: Es un error de precisión histórico de los números de coma flotante. Salvo que realmente necesites velocidad, siempre es recomendable utilizar `decimal`. Si quieres más información al respecto, puedes fijarte aquí: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753948/why-is-floating-point-arithmetic-in-c-sharp-imprecise

Answer (score 1):

No soy un experto en el tema pero hare mi mejor intento para explicarme.

Los tipos de `double` son conocidos por no ser precisos en sus calculo y esto debido a su composición. Los `doubles` son solo de 64 bit. Necesitas un tipo de dato con mas precisión y ese es el `decimal` que es de 128 bit. Cambia de `double` a `decimal` y deberia de funcionarte sin problemas:

```
 static void Motorprimario(decimal Nprimario, decimal Nfinal)
        {
            decimal numerodevuelto = 0, iposs = 0; int n1, n2, n3; bool jo = false, otramul = false;
            do
            {
                numerodevuelto = ((iposs * Nprimario) + Nfinal);

                if (jo == true)
                {
                    iposs -= (decimal)0.01;
                }
                else
                    iposs += (decimal)0.01;
            } while (numerodevuelto != 0);


        }
```

`Double` no se maneja muy bien cuando se requiere operaciones con resultados precisos, a diferencia de decimal. Por eso es que se utiliza `decimal` para calculos financieros por su precision. Solo que decimal mucho mas lento pero para tu caso no creo que haga la gran diferencia.

**Bonus**

Mira este ejemplo de lo impreciso que puede ser `double` comparados con los `decimal`:

```
  float f1 = 0.09f * 100f;
  float f2 = 0.09f * 99.999999f;

  decimal f1d = Convert.ToDecimal( 0.09f * 100d);
  decimal f2d = Convert.ToDecimal( 0.09f * 99.999999f);

   Console.WriteLine(f1 > f2); // False
   Console.WriteLine(f1d > f2d); // True
```

Comment: ok probare a ver si funciona, lo estaba corriendo en dev c++, pero dado al caso migrare el codigo a C#

Comment: ¿Cómo en C++? El tag que pusiste es C#. Igualmente me parece que no hay algo equivalente al `decimal` de .NET en C++. Si tienes que hacerlo en C++, las opciones son aplicar redondeo al hacer estas comparaciones, o bien si siempre utilizarás 2 decimales, multiplicar el valor por 100 y utilizar un `long`, aunque en este caso deberás ser cuidadoso de no multiplicar 2 valores que estén ya multiplicados por 100.

Comment: amigo una vez mas te agradezco me funciono y en el tag coloque c# porque tambien me daba error en c# en ambos y era por la declaracion de la variable tipo double! dado a que manejo ambos lenguajes pues tenia esa inquietud, una vez mas muchas gracias compañero saludos

Comment: Me alegra oir eso. Recuerda marcar la respuesta si la crees conveniente.